# Calculate the x and y based on bearing

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, geometry, trigonometry

I have a screen where I would like to calculate the next x and y based on angle.
The first footstep is this example starts at Step 1.
How can I calculate the next footstep where I want to increase going forward by 120 and the side step needs to weave in and out of about 60.

[image]

Please bear in mind that the starting point could be x = 100, y = 100 with the angle being 180 so the footsteps would have to then be going up the y axis.

I've attempted the following Javascript but the footsteps seem to get confused:

```
this.startingFootPrintX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 20; //Random number between 20 and 1000
this.startingFootPrintY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 560) + 20; //Random number between 20 and 560
this.startingAngle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 340) + 20; //Random number between 20 and 340

startFootSteps();

startFootSteps(){
console.log(this.startingFootPrintX);
console.log(this.startingFootPrintY);

this.startingFootPrintX = Math.round(Math.cos(this.startingAngle * Math.PI / 180) * 120 + this.startingFootPrintX);
this.startingFootPrintY = Math.round(Math.sin(this.startingAngle * Math.PI / 180) * 60 + this.startingFootPrintY);

setInterval(function () {
startFootSteps();
}, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diagram:

[image]

The step direction (black line) is given by `(cos θ, sin θ)`. The step offset direction (small blue lines) is given by `(sin θ, -cos θ)`

The position recurrence is given by:

[image]

`s` determines which side of the black line the next footprint is on, i.e. -1 for the left foot and +1 for the right.

If you know the starting position `c0` and the starting foot `s0`, a closed-form solution is given by:

[image]

This alternates between both feet for every step.

In your diagram example the parameters are `w = 60, d = 120, θ = 40°, c0 = (96, 438), s0 = -1` (starting with left foot).

---

UPDATE: JavaScript code snippet

```
this.startingPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 20;
this.startingPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 560) + 20;
this.startingAngle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 340) + 20;
this.startingFoot = 1 - 2 * Math.round(Math.random());   // select which foot to start with
this.stepSize = 120;
this.stepWidth = 60;

footsteps(0);

footsteps(n) {
    // should actually pre-calculate these outside but oh well
    let a = this.startingAngle * Math.PI / 180;
    let c = Math.cos(a), s = Math.sin(a);

    // current foot
    let d = this.startingFoot * (1 - 2 * (n % 2));

    // apply equations
    this.footprintX = Math.round(   
        this.startingPosX +             // initial
        this.stepSize * n * c +         // step
        this.stepWidth * 0.5 * d * s    // foot offset
    );
    this.footprintY = Math.round(
        this.startingPosY +             // initial
        this.stepSize * n * s -         // step
        this.stepWidth * 0.5 * d * c    // foot offset
    );

    // draw the foot here
    console.log(this.footprintX);
    console.log(this.footprintY);

    // increment the step counter for the next call
    setInterval(function() { footsteps(n+1); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've tried to condense what you're saying into a javascript solution but it's not working for me. Please could you give it a check? Thank you once again :)

Comment: @AndrewJunior what do you mean by "not working"? You didn't *completely* capture the equation (no side offset); I'll post sample code shortly.

Comment: The footsteps don't always move forward and sometimes they stamp over each other. Please bear in mind that the footsteps could be going from right to left of the screen as well but the angle would reflect that.
For example an angle between 0 and 180 would be going to the right, 180 to 360 would be going to the left.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward your math isn't consistent with the equation I wrote; you treat X and Y differently whereas a rotationally invariant system should not. I'll post code when I get the opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your code :) I think this bit doesn't know what b is = Math.sin(b)

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward oopsie that was a mistake on my part, fixed

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! That works great! Thanks so much, there was no way I would have worked that out!